# ms touch action allows zoom

Tags: windows, cordova, internet-explorer, microsoft-metro

I'm creating a cordova app for windows 8/8.1

I'm testing it on windows surface. I have the following css:

```css
    * {
        -ms-touch-action:pan-x;
        touch-action:pan-x;
    }
```

This is working, mostly, but if I start to pan with one finger and then, without releasing my finger, put down another finger and pinch in/out I still zoom in. I can only zoom when I start a pan gesture and turn it into a zoom. If I just try pinch to zoom by itself, I can't zoom in.

What can I do to stop this?